# Enabling SourceLink

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sourcelink

Having private repositories on VSTS (Azure DevOps) I tried enabling SourceLink by adding the following to the .csproj file: https://github.com/dotnet/sourcelink#azure-devops-visual-studio-team-services

This does not seem to have any effect during debugging. There is an exception thrown in a local NuGet package and I can not navigate to it using the Call Stack windows since the pdb is not even loaded for that project.

I have "Enable Just My Code" disabled and SourceLink enabled inside Visual Studio.

What other changes do I need to make to enable SourceLink?

Comment: the new csproj format doesn't copy PDBs from the nuget package to output dir, do this on your own

Comment: @magicandre1981https://github.com/dotnet/sourcelink#using-sourcelink seems to imply that there is a way to specify PDB generation

Comment: you miss the point. I talk about consuming nuget packages. Here the [new SDK has a bug](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/1458) where it doesn't copy the PDB to output, so no PDB + sourcelink info a present.

Answer (score 8):

Most of the tutorials on how to set up SourceLink seem to omit two key things.

Firstly:

- As well as unchecking "Enable Just My Code" (non-default) and making sure "Enable Source Link support" is checked (default) under Options/Debugging/General,
- If you want to work with SourceLink for public packages (say Newtonsoft.Json) you also have to check the listed symbol servers in VS Options/Debugging/Symbols.

Secondly:

- If you want to publish symbols for your own package onto a public feed (e.g. nuget.org) then AFAIK the `.snupkg` format works fine
- On a private NuGet feed (whether using a local file system NuGet feed, or the IIS `NuGet.Server` package) there is no symbol server, `.snupkg` is not supported, and this (which is widely listed as what to do instead) *does not work* (it includes the .pdb file in the NuGet package, but from my tests the consuming VS never uses them):

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <AllowedOutputExtensionsInPackageBuildOutputFolder>$(AllowedOutputExtensionsInPackageBuildOutputFolder);.pdb</AllowedOutputExtensionsInPackageBuildOutputFolder>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

- Using this instead, in the same place, does work (the pdb is embedded inside the dll itself, and the consuming VS sees it just fine):

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <DebugType>Embedded</DebugType>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

You should definitely check out the VS Modules window found under  Debug/Windows/Modules (shortcut CTRL+ALT+U) (only available while code is running), which shows which modules have loaded symbols and helps you figure out which haven't, and why not, if they haven't.

**EDIT**

It turns out that:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <AllowedOutputExtensionsInPackageBuildOutputFolder>$(AllowedOutputExtensionsInPackageBuildOutputFolder);.pdb</AllowedOutputExtensionsInPackageBuildOutputFolder>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

*is* working. It produces a NuGet file which is fine, or should be... but there is currently [a bug in .NET SDK](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/1458) which causes it not to load .pdb files stored in NuGet files in this way, although it should.

There is another fix. In the *consuming* project, include:

```
    <PackageReference Include="SourceLink.Copy.PdbFiles" Version="2.8.3" PrivateAssets="All" />
```

after adding that, everything should work again as per the demos.

Alternatively, the fix which that package applies is:

```
<Project>
  <Target Name="_ResolveCopyLocalNuGetPackagePdbs" AfterTargets="ResolveReferences"
      Condition="$(CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies) == true">
    <ItemGroup>
      <ReferenceCopyLocalPaths Include="@(ReferenceCopyLocalPaths->'%(RootDir)%(Directory)%(Filename).pdb')" 
          Condition="'%(ReferenceCopyLocalPaths.NuGetPackageId)' != '' and Exists('%(RootDir)%(Directory)%(Filename).pdb')" />
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

and (from [here](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/1458#issuecomment-409362480)):

> A good place to put it is in Directory.Build.targets so that your project files are not cluttered and so that you can apply it to multiple projects in a solution.
>   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-your-build

Comment: Thanks @MikeBeaton !  Adding the reference to `SourceLink.Copy.PdbFiles` did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

This may not be a direct answer, but it is well worth noting that you don't need SourceLink to get source level debugging. SourceLink is a clever way to put links in the PDB to source code in the cloud, in a git repo.

Another way to get portable source level debugging is to embed the source code directly in the PDB (`EmbedAllSources=True`), then embed the PDB in the DLL (`DebugType=embedded`). It's fairly efficient (20-30% larger .nupkg file) and doesn't suffer from the [bug](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/1458) currently affecting separate PDBs.

Just add this to your project file:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <EmbedAllSources>True</EmbedAllSources>
    <DebugType>embedded</DebugType>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

and lo and behold you will be able to single step into the NuGet file generated from it. No other workarounds and no SourceLink packages are required.

Comment: Using Embedded will add the source to the pdb right? how can i add the source in the snupkg package?